# Loading Local JSON in Angular on Stackblitz

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stackblitz

In general as noted here it's pretty straight forward:

```
import data from './data.json';
```

However this does not work in [Stackblitz Angular projects](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackblitz-json?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.json).

The linked project logs the following:

```
preview-3a0c9433aa42f56dbd90b.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Comment: why not put that json in a constant in a ts file?

Comment: I think that's a good idea ... Just curious whether there is a simple way to also import it in general?

Comment: I would suggest getting on their discord, they are pretty active there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When importing, you should not use `JSON.parse()`. It's already parsed by cli/webpack

```
import data from './data.json';

test: any = data;
```

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackblitz-json-uptt2q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @pierreDuc doesn't that SB use a .ts file with `export const data = {...` ?

Comment: @BenRacicot you are absolutely right, I guess I saved the stack at a wrong point when testing. I've updated it now